# Create array of incremental int using Stream instead of for loop

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I want to create a function that builds an array of incremental numbers.

For example, I want to obtain something like:

```
int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ..., 1000000};
```

The function will receive two parameters: start number (inclusive) and the final length of the array:

```
public int[] buildIncrementalArray(int start, int length) { ... }
```

I know how to do it using a for loop:

```
public int[] buildIncrementalArray(int start, int length) {
    int[] result = new int[length];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
        result[i] = start + i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Instead of using a for loop, I want to use Java 8 Stream API. Does anybody know how to do it using Stream API?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is already a built-in method for that:

```
int[] array = IntStream.range(start, start + length).toArray();
```

[`IntStream.range`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) returns a sequential ordered `IntStream` from the start (inclusive) to the end (exclusive) by an incremental step of 1.

If you want to include the end element, you can use [`IntStream.rangeClosed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-).

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way using `IntStream`,

```
int[] array = new int[length];
IntStream.range(0, length).forEach(i -> array[i] = i + 1);
```

Please let me know if it does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you find for light code then you may use this one

```
int[] myArray = new int[n];
while(n-- >= 0){
    myArray[n] = n+1;
}
```